# Converting class to hooks (state inside if statement)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have old code which is in a class, I need to convert it to hooks. I have now converted everything successfully except one code where `state` is declared inside if statement, other codes which I convert had `this.setState` inside if statement. How to convert it to hooks?

```
 if (this.props.curentAnalyser) {
            this.state = {
                ...this.state,
                name: this.props.curentAnalyser.name,
                destination: this.props.curentAnalyser.destination_id,
                cameras: this.props.curentAnalyser.cameras,
                reset_time: this.props.curentAnalyser.reset_time
            };
        }
```

should those be converted for example to:
setReset_time( props.curentAnalyser.reset_time) ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work about that attempt? May you share a [mcve] so we can know what `setReset_time` is?

Comment: i dont know how to convert that part, thats why asking, cuz state is declared inside if and i usually declare it at top

Comment: Is it inside the `componentDidMount` function?

Comment: @SinanYaman no it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these are the state variables, you need to use the `useState` hook.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const ExampleComponent = props => {
 const { curentAnalyser } = prop 
 const [compState, setCompState] = useState(currentAnalyzer)

}
```

This will set the `compState` to the `currentAnalyzer` object.
and you can change the `compState` when you need as such:

```
setCompState(cs => ({
  ...cs,
  [anyField] : anyValue
})
```

#### Method 2

You can set the state by using `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(currentAnalyzer) setCompState(currentAnalyzer)
}, [currentAnalyzer]
```

Comment: why havent you used if statement here ?

Comment: and where is '...this.state,' part  ?

Comment: [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: could you possibly use my code and convert it so i could learn from it ?

Comment: What do you mean use your code? You can't use the same code in class and functional component. There is no `this.state` in functional component. There is no `this` keyword at all. You lack some research, therefore I sent you a link.

Comment: i know there is no this keyword i mean other parts such as 'name: this.props.curentAnalyser.name,
                destination: props.curentAnalyser.destination_id,
                cameras: props.curentAnalyser.cameras,
                reset_time: props.curentAnalyser.reset_time'

Comment: They are all inside the `currentAnalyser` in my code. So the `compState` will look like: `{name: "value of name",  destination: "value of destination", cameras: ..., reset_time: ... }`

Comment: so 'setCompState' goes inside that if statement ?

Comment: Updated the answer, you can check it

Comment: sorry that i'm asking but above that i have state already '  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props = props;
    this.state = {
      helperText: { name: "" },
      error: { name: false },
      mode: ADD,
      showModeSelector: true,
      readOnly: false,
      name: "",
      destination: "",
      reset_time: "",
    };'  so in my question code is that spreading state '                ...this.state,
' coming from this state here ?

Comment: Yeah, it is spreading the state and changes fields accordingly.

Comment: but in your code its spreading code from props which comes from here 'mapStateToProps' i mean this part 'cs => ({
  ...cs,' isnt it different ?

Comment: cs refers to the current state there. It was an example to update the state, not necessary while converting this part of the code.

Comment: can it be done like this for example :   if (props.currentAnalyser) {
setHelperText({ name: "" })
      setError( { name: false })
      setMode(ADD)
setName(props.currentAnalyser.name)
setDestination(props.currentAnalyser.destination_id)
setCameras(props.currentAnalyser.cameras)
setReset_time(props.currentAnalyser.reset_time)
}

Comment: Yeah, of course. You need seperate `useState` for each field and you are good to go. Although, it is not very performant to call `setState` hook multiple times back to back. That is why I condensed them into a one state.

Answer (score 1):

Like you can read in the documentation

> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

For state you need to use useState() function

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

And for lifecycle you need to use useEffect() function base on your state

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // do something
  }, [count]);
```